# Trouble making nginx works with symfony in subdirectory

Tags: nginx, symfony

This question is imported from SO. I kept the edit made with the comments so we dont have to go over it once more :). The link to the OP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57503107/trouble-making-nginx-works-with-symfony-in-subdirectory

I'm trying to setup Symfony 4 next to an already working wordpress site with nginx. Wordpress should manage the homepage at

> https://www.my.domain

and the blog posts under

> https://www.my.domain/conseils

The symfony application should take over for anything under

> https://www.my.domain/app

I've read the default documentation bot [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/symfony/) and [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html) aswell as some troubleshooting made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775627/symfony-app-in-a-subdirectory-in-nginx-for-an-existing-site). Furthermore, it seems REALLY close to that answered question but with nginx instead of apache: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53895202/symfony4-routing-inside-a-subfolder

The fact is i still cant manage to make it working. Here's my current site.conf which gives me a 404, but i cant really find some helpful log even with the debug option enabled in nginx.

```
    server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    server_name www.my.domain;
    root /var/www/my.domain/html;


    #symfony location block
    location /app {
        alias /var/www/my.domain/app/public;
        index index.php;

        try_files $uri /app/public/index.php/$1 last;

        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;


        error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
    }

    #Wordpress location block
    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;



        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~* \.(css|js|ico|gif|jpeg|jpg|webp|png|svg|eot|otf|woff|woff2|ttf|ogg)$ {
         expires max;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }

    }

}
```

Lastly i tried something found [here](https://gist.github.com/marcw/2bebd7094b649a627a171ee1d5e34b26). This times, it gives me the following symfony routing error: No route found for "GET /app".
Below the conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    server_name www.my.domain;
    root /var/www/my.domain/html;


    # Symfony location block
    location /app {
        alias /var/www/my.domain/app/public;
        index index.php;

        rewrite ^/app/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        try_files $uri @symfonyFront;


    }
        set $symfonyRoot /var/www/my.domain/app/public;
        set $symfonyScript index.php;
        location @symfonyFront {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $symfonyRoot/$symfonyScript;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /app/$symfonyScript;
                fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI /app$uri?$args;
        }

    #Wordpress location block
    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;



        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~* \.(css|js|ico|gif|jpeg|jpg|webp|png|svg|eot|otf|woff|woff2|ttf|ogg)$ {
         expires max;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }

    }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.my.domain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.my.domain/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

In both cases, the wordpress is working as intended. Homepage and blog posts are showing when expected. The symfony app however isnt. For the former cas, i got a 404 when visiting my.domain/app and the latter gives me a symfony routing error. That means i'm actually hitting SF front controller. And i got the kernel stack trace saying the route app/ is not found within symfony. And that's absolutely correct since i expect symfony to work under that directory and it should not be user for the routing.

At this point i'm not even sure which one makes me close to the desired result. Any tip would be appreciated!

EDIT:
etc/nginx/error.log with debug activated show many lines but this one caught my attention:

> 2019/08/15 18:11:42 [alert] 6929#6929: *5 "alias" cannot be used in
>   location "/app" where URI was rewritten, client: 86.252.250.94,
>   server: www.my.domain, request: "GET /app/ HTTP/1.1", host:
>   "www.my.domain"

And when i got the route not found error, i got that (which is expected) in the symfony log:

> [2019-08-15 18:26:00] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /app"" at /var/www/my.domain/app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 141 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /app\" at /var/www/my.domain/app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:141, Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"/app/\". at /var/www/my.domain/app/vendor/symfony/routing/Matcher/Dumper/CompiledUrlMatcherTrait.php:70)"} []

EDIT2: i've added the

> fastcgi_split_path_info ^/app(.+.php)(/.+)$;

without noticeable change.
Interestingly enough, when i replaced the rewrite directive with "last" instead of "break" it displays the 404 page from wordpress.

EDIT:
fastcgi-php.conf

```
@www:~$ sudo cat /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf
# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
```

Comment: For a similar setup (wp in a subfolder with another wp in root folder) a simple reverse proxy for the specific location worked perfectly. So you just proxy_pass /app to your another nginx vhost listening eg localhost:8080.. give it a try

Answer (score 0):

First "bug" is having prefixed location (`location /something`) without trailing slash. It needs to be `location /app/ {`, otherwise the location matches `app123`.

The `try_files` in the app location is over-complicated. Keep it simple:

```
try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
```

Considering you retain your current file structure:

- /var/www/my.domain/html - Wordpress
- /var/www/my.domain/app - Symfony

Then:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name www.my.domain;
    root /var/www/my.domain/html;

    #Wordpress location block
    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        location ~* \.(css|js|ico|gif|jpeg|jpg|webp|png|svg|eot|otf|woff|woff2|ttf|ogg)$ {
         expires max;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }
    }

    #symfony location block
    location ^~ /app/ {
        index index.php;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
        alias /var/www/my.domain/app/public/;
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock; 
            # important to use $request_filename with alias
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        }
    }

    # redirect /app to app/
    location = /app {
        return 301 /app/;
    }   

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Danlia, and sorry for the late reply, i took 2 days off. When doing that, i get the following error from `nginx -t `: 
nginx: [emerg] "alias" directive is duplicate, "root" directive was specified earlier in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my.domain:151
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
I tried so swap them, but didnt manage to make it work as expected. WHen only root is specified to the public/ directory, then i got a 404 generated by Wordpress. Symfony doesnt seem to be triggered.

Comment: @KévinBruneau see the updated answer. Let me know if it works :)

Comment: /app is redirected to /app/ which leads to a wordpress 404. No error in nginx.log, Entry in access log seems fine.

Comment: Do you want me to add debug log to nginx ? If so, tell me what i should search in it :)

Comment: Can you list contents of `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf`?

Comment: oops, i edited your answer too! Please ignore it x) Main question edited.

Comment: Hum, i can see the snippets use script_name, and i set script_filename. Could it be sth here ?

Comment: Nope, it's a bit too much already (many configs, much to be broken). `try_files ` shouldn't be in PHP handler; check contents of `fastcgi.conf` as well; don't include `fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;`

Comment: I commented both line. Fastcgi.conf only defines params, nothing weird here. I used debug log from nginx. It shows that symfony controller is never called. Only wordpress index. It looks like the file /app/public/index.php is never called at all

Comment: Then what error you get in error.log while accessing /app/ ?

Comment: There's no error at all, only debug message. It tries every location block (including "app") to finally set fastcgi_param: "SCRIPT_FILENAME: /var/www/my.domain/html/index.php"